# Discord.js / Node.js - await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, discord

Why is this happening???

```
 try {
            var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(`I could not join to the voice channel: ${error}`);
            return message.channel.send(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error message. You can't use the `await` statement inside a function that isn't declared as `async`.

Incorrect:

```
function doSomething() {
  var result = await doSomethingElse()
}
```

Correct:

```
async function doSomethingAsync() {
  var result = await doSomethingElse()
}
```

More information on async functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) at MDN.